# Markov inequality

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence

Suppose, $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. r.v.s such that

$P(X_{n}=e^n)=\frac{1}{n^2}$; $P(X_{n}=0)=1-\frac{1}{n^2}$

Therefore, show that $X_{n}$ converges to $0$ in probability.

Ans:
By, Markov inequality,

$P(|X_{n}|>\epsilon)=P(X_{n}>\epsilon)<\frac{E(X_{n})}{\epsilon}=\frac{e^n}{\epsilon n^2}\nrightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Is it wrong???

Comment: It doesn't even seem to be an answer: you haven't demonstrated convergence in probability.

Answer (score 3):

Markov's inequality gives you an upper bound for $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)$, as you've shown, but this upper bound does not tend to zero. It does not follow that $X_n$  fails to converge to zero in probability. If you are asked to prove that $P(A)\le \frac12$ for some event $A$, and the best you can come up with is that $P(A)\le1$, it doesn't follow that the claim is false; rather, you need another approach.

For the problem at hand, don't use Markov's inequality. You need a sharper upper bound. Hint: argue that for any $\epsilon>0$, the event $\{|X_n|>\epsilon\}$ is the same as the event $\{X_n = e^n\}$, which has probability $\frac1{n^2}$.